# Right-hand rule of EM waves (electric, magnetic field and direction of propagation)

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electric-fields

According to my physics book, the electric field, the magnetic field and the direction of propagation obey to right-hand rule.
Anyway I am not sure why in the pictures below the book states that $B = \sqrt{B_z^2 + B_y^2}$ and $B^2 = B_z^2 + B_y^2$

$$\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}=\left|\begin{matrix}\mathbf{i}&\mathbf{j}&\mathbf{k}\\0&E_y&E_z\\0&B_y&B_z\end{matrix}\right|=(E_yB_z-E_zB_y)i=(vB_x^2+vB_y^2)\mathbf{i}=vB^2\mathbf{i}$$

$$E=\sqrt{E_y^2+E_z^2}=\sqrt{v^2B_z^2+v^2B_y^2}=v\sqrt{B_z^2+B_y^2}=vB$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is just vector addition. They’re calculating the total length of the $B$ vector from its $y$ and $z$ components, so they use the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: https://gmw.com/technicalnotes/magnetic-field-vectors/ Is It the same thing?

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi yep, looks like the same thing!